# How to cleanly remove pleated blinds from thermopane windows?

Tags: windows, adhesive, blinds

I have some pleated blinds stuck to the thermopane window frames of my apartment. It's the kind that sticks to the frame, you don't need to drill holes (this is it: https://www.amazon.co.uk/IKEA-SCHOTTIS-Pleated-blind-90x190/dp/B00RK4U1DK).

I tried to remove one but the material just detached itself from the glue and the frame, with the glue being stuck on the window frame.

How can I safely remove the blinds from the window? By safely I mean not using some toxic or intense smelling substance and not damaging the window frame?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to remove the glue band from the window. The glue was too strong.

[image]

I noticed that if I push really hard with my fingers up on the glue tape it starts to pull together.

[image]

[image]

That didn't last for long since it was very hard to pull it together and as a result my fingers really started to hurt.

I eventually used medicinal alcohol to soak the glue band and make it more soft then using an alcohol damp cloth I pushed the tape together. The alcohol evaporated fast so the glue hardened again so I had to work 5-10 cm at a time.

[image]

After a few hours, some tired arms and hurt fingers I managed to remove it completely with no damage to the frame.